# How to indent with chrome dev editor?

Tags: google-chrome, indentation, chrome-dev-editor

I've search around the internet and the Chrome Dev Editor options, but didn't find the shortcut to indent my code. I've tried a lot of shortcuts already, perhaps I missed one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the extent is same as other Chromebook  defaults.

Shift-Down - to select
tab to indent
shift-tab to outdent

Comment: That was pretty intresting thanks. But that's not exactly what I wanted to do. I would like to do the same thing as in SublimeText : Ctrl +A ,and, Ctrl+Shift+P "indent". Or in webstorm : Ctrl+A ,and, Ctrl+Alt+I.